# Dojox tooltips don't show up on mouse over

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, tooltip

I am getting crazy while rendering a simple line chart with dojo toolkit. Everything is fine except that tooltips don't show up on mouse over. ChartData is a list of objects having this 
structure:

```
    [{'x':x1, 'y':y1, 'tooltip':"some text"}, {...}, ...]
```

The magnify animation works on both Chrome and Firefox. I tried to change theme as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085203/dojox-chart-highlight-effect-not-working) but still no results.
What I am doing wrong?

```
    require([ 
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
        "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
        "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
        "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
        "dojox/charting/action2d/Magnify"],
        function(Chart, Tooltip, Magnify, themes, Lines, Default) {
        var chartData = data["res"];
        var chart = new Chart("graph", {title: data["title"], 
                              titleFontColor: "#79B30B"});

        chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, min: 0, max:110});
        chart.addAxis("x");
        chart.addPlot("default", { type: "Lines", markers: true, 
                                   tension:3,
                                   shadows: {dx: 2, dy: 2, dw: 2} } );
        chart.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice);
        chart.addSeries("Connectivity[%]", chartData);
        var tooltip = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart, "default");
        var magnify = new dojox.charting.action2d.Magnify(chart, "default");
        chart.render();
      });
```

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using? Your code seems to work fine for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/froden/xk9wN/

Comment: The Dojo version is 1.8.1 as in your example. Using the js console I noticed that there is a div containing tooltip and appear only in chrome <div class="dijitTooltip dijitTooltipLeft"...>. But is outside the chart!!

Comment: Ah, I'm suspect that means you don't have a dijit theme loaded, or that you don't have `class="claro"` on your body tag. Tooltips are usually inserted into the DOM at the end of your body, so don't worry that it isn't inside the chart element. Try adding a dijit theme (e.g. claro like in my example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks Frode, the solution is to load the dijit theme in the head of the HTML page 
In my code  will be MiamiNice instead of Claro.

```
  <style type="text/css">
  @import
  url("http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css");
  </style>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to place the @import in my css file or place a css link in the head like so `<link href="http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`.  When I placed the @import in my head I saw a runtime error.

Comment: P.S.  I have three charts on one page each using a different theme.  I only needed to include one theme in my css to get all three to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my tooltips were not being shown on a line chart.  I changed markers:false to markers:true when adding the plot to the chart and the tooltips started to show up.

```
mapChart1.addPlot("default", {
    type : dojox.charting.plot2d.Lines,
    markers : true
});
```